# Creating a bash script to ping and traceroute multiple websites (OSX)

Tags: macos, bash

I have a Mac and I would like to ping and traceroute multiple websites over several days and save those data to a .txt file. I found out that using bash script I can automate this process instead of commanding and copying results.

Unfortunately I was not able to find enough information to do this by myself so I am posting a question here.

**For example:**

```
ping -c 1 google.com
```

Result in .txt file:

```
PING google.com (210.7.45.30): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 210.7.45.30: icmp_seq=0 ttl=61 time=8.595 ms
```

So how do I create a bash file to ping and traceroute multiple websites and put the results into a single txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the commands into a file and execute it:

```
#!/bin/sh
OUTPUTFILE=~/output.txt
ping -c 1 site1 >> $OUTPUTFILE
traceroute site1 >> $OUTPUTFILE
```

etc.

Comment: Do I write that on a .txt and convert it to .sh file?

Comment: ".sh" files are just text files.  The extension makes no difference at all.  After you write it, simply execute it using your shell or mark it as executable using chmod and execute it directly.

Comment: I get an error message saying permission denied. When I put sudo in front of the .txt file directory, I get an error saying command not found...

Comment: The method you posted doesn't seem to work if I am pinging more than 4 websites

Comment: It will work for any number of sites.  Verify that you haven't mistyped a '>>' as a '>' or post your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about the `>` operator which writes the content to the file instead of standard output. The `>>` operator append the output to the file. For example following command saves the list of the files of current directory fo the file `files.txt`:

```
ls > files.txt
```

In your case you simply need to send the output of pings to the file rather than the standard output:

```
ping -c 1 google.com > data.txt
```

If you want to merge the data of multiple website you can open multiple tabs and run the following command:

```
ping -c 1 [put_the_url_here] >> ~/data.txt
```

Notice the `>>` operator that makes the data to appended to the bottom of the same file.

Then you can use a tool like `awk` to convert the data to CSV format and filter it using your spreadsheet program.